# How to set up width of columns in WinForms datagridview properly?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with some data inside. Some of its contents is long. I have the following requirements:

1. Immediately after loading no scrolling should be shown.
2. If content is longer than width of column it should be clipped.
3. User can resize any column.
4. If summarized width of content is less that the width of the table the columns should be stretched.

Comment: Two things: First, if you spend a few minutes approving some answers to your questions, you will likely get more attention to your current and future questions. Second, this question doesn't seem like a question but a set of project requirements. Not to be rude, but frankly we aren't here to build programs for you.  We are here to aid you in your attempts to build programs.  The set of requirements you have are only a part of what your question should be. The next parts should be what you've tried and why that hasn't been satisfactory.